# How to configure java app to write printstacktrace in file without changing code?

Tags: java, exception, eclipse-rcp

I'm working on an existing eclipse application. And all exceptions are printed with a e.printstacktrace(). I would like to know if it's possible to print the exceptions in a log file only by adding VM args or Eclipse args in the INI file. I would like not to change all printstacktrace() of the program.

Thanks for yours answers

Comment: Too broad. You can look into redirecting the standard error stream.

Comment: Would you be executing your program through eclipse on production as well? Or you just want it for debug purpose?

Comment: I would like to produce log file with produced version of eclipse app only

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("log.txt"));
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
printstacktrace(ps);
```

Comment: But I have to do this for all exceptions. I would like to avoid it

Comment: That is why you should use logging framework like logback or log4j and instead of printing exceptions directly. you should log them using this frameworks' API. you can choose whether you want to log to console or file - or maybe skip some messages. Logging framework give you these facilities.

Comment: This is what I would do if I had started the project, but now I would have to change all existing exception. Is there a way to correct automatically all printstacktrace ?